# Cordova App - Build Failing on XCode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, cordova

I'm currently running iOS 7.1 beta 5 on my iPhone 5S, and I also am running Xcode51-Beta5. I'm new to app development in general, but definitely know my way around Xcode and code in general as I come from a PHP background.

There is a Hello World application that is compiled with Cordova, which you can open in Xcode to emulate on an iOS device or deploy to your device for testing.

Without tweaking anything, the Hello World app runs fine on all simulators for iOS devices, however, when I attempt to deploy it to my iPhone 5S, I get 10 build errors and it fails. I tried turning off Code Signing for the project which was suggested in another Stackoverflow question, however, that also didn't work.

The errors I get: http://prntscr.com/2tqqj3 and in more detail: http://prntscr.com/2tqqse

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post the exact error message, and the [code necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am getting exactly those errors. I just updated Cordova to 3.4.0-0.1.3 and ran `cordova build ios` again but to no avail. Did you manage to find a solution or workaround?

Comment: `cordova build` seems to be broke on Xcode 7 beta as well. Resetting to default Xcode.app will fix it `sudo xcode-select -r`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Cordova, but it appears that the required architecture (arm64) for iPhone5S is missing from the library. It should work perfectly with non-64-bit devices.

Comment: This is what I'm guessing as well. Might be worth looking into compiling Cordova from source if the binaries for arm64 aren't available.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334680/xcode-5-1-libcordova-a-architecture-problems), which has some suggested answers.

Also see the  Apache Cordova JIRA issue at: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6223