# xcode 5.1: libCordova.a architecture problems

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcode5.1

Yesterday (3/10/14) when iOS 7.1 was released I also upgraded to Xcode 5.1 and found that my PhoneGap/Cordova project would no longer compile to my iPhone 5s. I also upgraded Cordova to the most recent release: v 3.4.0-0.1.3.

I have read many different solutions on SO that relate so changing active architectures and building only active architectures, and none of them work. So here's what I've tried and the errors I get. Initially I got the error:

```
missing required architecture arm64 in file <long file path omitted> libCordova.a
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
```

So I tried the following. I selected the CordovaLib sub-project in my project, and in both the project and target, I went to **Build Settings** under **Architectures** and made sure that `arm64` was not included in any of the Debug or Release architectures. At this time **Build Active Architecture Only** is set to "Yes". That resulted in the following error:

```
file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): 
<long file path omitted> libCordova.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7
```

Setting **Build Active Architecture Only**  to "No", the error again becomes:

```
missing required architecture arm64 in file <long file path omitted> libCordova.a
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
```

I'm not sure what else to try. The project's architecture settings only includes the key "Base SDK" which is set to iOS 7.1. The project's target does not have architectures settings. Anyway I'm fairly certain the problem lies with the embedded CordovaLib sub-project. What can I do to make this thing compile to my device successfully?

Update: same issue on Apache's Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6223

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. iOS 7.1 and Xcode 5.1 have been available to developers for some time, so it's disappointing that the Cordova team didn't at least issue a warning about this before they were released.

Comment: Yea. I created a brand new 'Hello World' Cordova Project with the most recent Cordova installed and it wouldn't compile successfully.

Comment: Is it possible to get hold of and reinstall the iOS 7.0 SDK ?

Comment: I got it to compile using [these settings](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/618674/_perma/2014-03/xcode.png) but when I go to Validate the archive I get the error: **This bundle is invalid. Apps that include an armv7s architecture are required to include an armv7 architecture. Which is weird because it looks like I _have_ included both.

Comment: Yes, you can do it in iTunes with your phone connected to your Mac. But you won't be able to release your app because it won't run on iOS 7.1...

Comment: I have managed to compile and validate my existing app with just the 'armv7' architecture selected in both the Project and Target. I'm not sure what the implications are of not including armv7s and arm64. Will it not run on an iPhone 5S ?

Comment: Nope, I don't believe they will compile to a 5s without `armv7s`.

Comment: Fix steps in the Apache Cordova JIRA issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6223.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

@Shazron posted the fix on the Apache JIRA - he notes that the fix will be released as part of Cordova 3.5:

1. Select your Project icon
2. Choose Build Settings.
3. For "Architectures", select $ARCHS_STANDARD - Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s, arm64)
4. For "Valid Architectures", add "arm64"
5. Select your CordovaLib.xcodeproj icon
6. In the Build Settings for the Project (not Target), delete the conditional architecture settings (hover to see the minus sign)
7. For "Architectures", select $ARCHS_STANDARD - Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s, arm64)
8. For "Valid Architectures", add "arm64"
9. Goto 6, but now do it for "Target"

Here's a link to Shazron's complete writeup of this problem: http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/xcode-5-1-and-cordova-ios/

It is now released and the short version of what to do is:

Cordova CLI  3.4.1-0.1.0 is out, which includes Cordova iOS 3.4.1 which incorporates all the fixes mentioned in this blog post. Update your Cordova CLI, and if you have an existing project, do a “cordova platform update ios“.

Comment: Excellent. For step #6 am I correct in thinking I should delete ALL of these: [SCREENSHOT](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/618674/_perma/2014-03/contitional-architectures.png) ?

Comment: It _seems ok_ at first: The app archives, and validates. But when exported as an ad hoc distribution it will not run on an iPhone 5S.

Comment: Yes, this answer gets the app to compile and install on a 5S, but when it starts to run it throws an lldb error and crashes (or pauses if you're running your device tethered to your Mac while running Xcode).

Comment: Here is the link to @Shazron post. It covers 3 issues:
http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/xcode-5-1-and-cordova-ios/

Comment: I confirm it works for me. Do not forget point 9 which is to remove any conditional architecture settings for target 'Cordova Lib'.
You should have for both Project 'CordovaLib' and targets 'CordovaLib'.
Architecture settings should looks :

- Debug : Standard architecture (...)
- Release : Standard architecture (...)

Comment: By removing all of the conditional architectures, while it allowed me to compile the app, it broke some of my plugins.  I am now getting "not found, or is not a CDVPlugin" errors.  Be careful and make a backup of your project.

Comment: I've found this solution works great provided you don't validate (it undoes your changes)... @njtman what plugins don't work? I have a ton of plugins that are working just fine.

Comment: @inorganik they are specific cordova plugins compiled for enterprise that are not generally available to the public.  they will need to re-compile them to work with arm64 I suppose.  In the mean time I downgraded Xcode and all is good.

Comment: I was on a previous version of Cordova (3.3.0) which required some additional steps I posted here along with some pics for what @stechbach points out: http://wp.me/pxvmV-6x. Thanks for this!

Comment: Excellent. I was confused with 15 strange errors, and now they're gone :). Thanks.

Comment: This solution worked well for me once I'd also changed all instances of Build Active Architecture Only to No.

Comment: Just had to do this for iOS 8 and XCode 6. It force an update to 5.1.1 for OS deployment minimum target but that is OK by me.

Answer (score 11):

Another approach that works:

1. Click on your project at the top of the project navigator (not the Cordova.lib subproject).
2. In the editor pane, select the project (not the target), select the Build Settings editor tab, and click the All and Levels buttons.
3. Expand the Architectures group if necessary and find the Architectures row under it.
4. The first (resolved) and third (iOS Default) columns in the Architecture row will say Standard; the second (project) column will be blank.
5. Click on the blank second column to bring up a box that will have one line, “$(ARCHS_STANDARD)”.
6. Double-click that line to make it editable, then change it to read “$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)”.
7. Click outside the box to confirm your change. Now the first and second boxes will just have a $ in them.
8. Now you should be able to build.

Answer (score 10):

Downgrade Xcode 5.1 to 5.0.2 worked for me, I could not wait for an official Cordova 3.5 release with the fix.

You can get a copy of the previous version here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Comment: This works - the only caveat being that you can't test directly in XCode on an iPhone that is running iOS 7.1. This is where the simulator comes in handy. The compiled app _can_ run on iOS 7.1 (confirmed on both an iPhone 5 and 5S) so downgrading till Cordova 3.5 is released seems the best option.

Comment: This works for me best right now too. Downloaded Xcode 5.02 and copied it (naming it XCode_502 first) to Applications enabled me to run it next to Xcode 5.1.

Comment: Ade I have downgraded to 5.0.2 and have been testing my app on iPhone  5 and iPad 2 both with iOS 7.1, with no problems, I have also submitted the app to iTunes Connect with no problems.

Answer (score 8):

They just released a new version [3.4.1](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-ios.git;a=commitdiff;h=a96d2360fa9cf5bb3006abc37bc88b81d87286d3) that address this issues.

Therefore I update a single file to point to the TAG 3.4.1:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/platforms.js
```

line 24 
from:

```
version: '3.4.0'
```

to:

```
version: '3.4.1'
```

Then you remove the iOS folder in your project and run:

```
cordova platform add ios
```

This will download the new template based on 3.4.1 with all the patches.

Comment: npm update cordova -g, then cordova platform update ios

Answer (score 5):

Follow the instructions on this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIkJAKcz8DE

Just add arm64 in your projects valid architectures and remove all the conditional architecture of Cordova's project.

Comment: You just saved me soooo much headache. This video fixed the issue I was struggling with for a few hours.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for making the video - it made it very clear.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get my app to build in XCode 5.1 by first building the CordovaLib project separately from within XCode and then building my project.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Perfect, since downgrading Xcode (and not being able to test on iOS7.1 devices) is not an option for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You just have to add the arm64 architecture on every statement and building setting, i mean,
on your current project, and on the cordova project.

On your project:

- Architectures
- Valid architectures

on Cordova:

- Architectures
- debug
- release
- Any ios SDK

AND THE MOST IMPORTANT

-Valid architectures at cordova build settings

This configuration generates a lot of warnings, but is just change the **"%d"** for **"%ld"** at all lines that the warning says.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the xcode icon and drag it to the bin!

Go here https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode and download 5.0.2 and install.

After installing, run xcode, then try the emulator from terminal.

Worked for me, annoying though!