# PhoneGap iOS application broken after OS X & XCode update

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

This evening I came home to find my computer needing updates. Instead of clicking 'Remind Me Later', I accidentally hit Install.

Now whenever I try to run my app in XCode, I get 32 warnings and 14 errors.

The main error seems to be

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/matcartmill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Loaner-exieykzxfldkzxbzhnndzmfucudg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /Users/matcartmill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Loaner-exieykzxfldkzxbzhnndzmfucudg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a
```

All of the errors after this one are all Apple Mach-o Linked Errors.

A mostly complete list of errors can be seen at http://cardeninteractive.com/help/loaner/errors.png

I have tried eliminating arm64 from the build options, but that just creates more errors. I have cleaned up my DerivedData and tried to recompile with no luck. I have also tried rebuilding the app in PhoneGap, with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. It's an issue with Phonegap, but should be fixed in 3.5.0. In the meantime, this fix worked for me: [xcode 5.1: libCordova.a architecture problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334680/xcode-5-1-libcordova-a-architecture-problems)

For more info, see the Jira issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6223?jql=project%20%3D%20CB%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20priority%20%3D%20Major%20ORDER%20BY%20key%20DESC

Answer (score 0):

This is a Cordoba bug at the moment, fix will be released as part of Cordova 3.5.
Here is the ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6223

A temporal solution for this problem could be uninstalling Xcode 5.1, get Xcode 5.0.2 here https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action and keep working with that until the bug is fixed