# Apple Mach-O Linker Error on Project Archive

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cordova

I'm building an iOS app using Cordova. The project runs perfectly fine in the simulator and on my device. However, when I go create an IPA (product > archive) I get 9 weird Apple Mach-O Linker Errors?

I have no idea what these are / what they mean as I'm not an xcode developer - some guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

I've read on here that it could be due to duplicate files, however there are no duplicates/missing assets in the project.

Screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/2c0z0I1q2x2p

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode 5.1: libCordova.a architecture problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334680/xcode-5-1-libcordova-a-architecture-problems)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

It appears to be an error with cordova 3.4.0 - fixed with a patch in 3.4.1

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22876525/3033858