# missing 64-bit support when validating IOS build

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, 64-bit, arm64

My MAC OS version is `10.8.5` and xcode version is `Version 5.1.1 (5B1008)`

I have an IOS app which i was trying to update to app store. In the usual process which i used to do everytime, now i have `cleaned build, created an Archive(Product>Archeive)` and tried to validate it by clicking on Validate button after archieve build has been created, but i was facing the below error

[image]

My build settings are

[image]

So whats the problem here ? and how to avoid this error ?

I read somewhere on google to update the `valid Architecture with arm64`, and when i added `arm64` to valid architecture setting and when tried to create a build(tried to create an archieve) then i was getting a lot of errors and build/code was not working

So can anyone please take me through steps to fix the above issue ?

After updating Valid Architecture setting to below

[image]

and when tried to create an archive the build failed and the errors are

[image]

**Edit**

Also the framework in which my app was built on `Cordova framework`

Comment: Yes, you will also have to update the frameworks also in your project which do not support arm64. Adding only arm64 in your architectures does not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have no option but to add arm64 to Valid architectures. So removing it to avoid errors is not a solution.

Instead, add arm64 back to your valid architectures and try to solve errors.
If you cant solve yourself, search for solutions on this site, or ask new question, people will help you out..

**In short, SOLUTION :**

Add arm64 to your valid architectures and solve arising errors.

Comment: the word errors means the complete code was breaking at almost all places and not just one or two errors

Comment: I understand, but you have no other option. It is because you are using a version of library that doesn't support arm64 architecture. Please upgrade to a library that supports arm64. I am sure if it is cordova, they have an upgrade to support this

Answer (score 0):

Type "arm64" in the Valid Architectures

Comment: i have edited the question with your change and got many errors

Answer (score 0):

**As of Feb 1, 2015 apple allows the app to be submitted with arm64 support.**

You have no option to submit your app without adding `arm64` support.

By adding support for `arm64` support, it will cause errors if you have used frameworks which do not support `arm64` support.

You will have to update your frameworks which do not support arm64.

Also, update your architectures from Build Settings to `Standard architectures(armv7,arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)`.

Once done, then and the only you will be able to archive successfully and submit the app to app Store.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: oh ok yeah my app was desinged on cordova framework, do you have any idea on how to update it ?

Comment: Also i have used Build Settings to Standard architectures(armv7,arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD) now ?

Comment: May be try with https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios or https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to support arm64 with Cordova follow this post [xcode 5.1: libCordova.a architecture problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334680/xcode-5-1-libcordova-a-architecture-problems)

Otherwise **@Mayur Deshmukh** and others are right! You have no choice but supporting *arm64* now.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the errors you have received, it would appear that the cordova framework you have used does not yet support arm64. 
I experienced the same problem with a different framework and was able to solve it by contacting the creator of the framework, i would suggest doing this to see if there is an updated framework available.